# codeigniter 404 on VM

Tags: codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I just setup a VM server on my computer with ssh and git and all that good stuff...  it works perfectly..  except this damn 404..

I've enabled `mod_rewrite`, so that's working as intended..

I created my codeigniter directory, for this example we'll call it `testsite`

When I visit: `http://192.168.*.*/testsite`, it redirects me to `http://192.168.*.*/testsite/login` as it's supposed to..

But, i get a 404 Not Found error in doing so...  But, when I create a `VirtualHost` and set the `ServerAlias` to `testsite` -- then on the development machine setting in my hosts file `192.168.*.* testsite.dev` and going to `http://testsite.dev` it works flawlessly..

I've tried adding a `RewriteBase` to my `.htaccess` to no avail...

I'm at my wits end trying to figure out why it's giving me a 404 when it clearly exists... Any help appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

clearly when you try to visit your VM *( which is not a localhost to you )* the server will not let you see the page with **403** error. but as long as you are getting **404** then the VM server is not understanding your request and at the same time it can't consider that you don't have the right permissions. so it gives you **404** instead of **403**. and yes by adding the virtual host you made the VM understands the situation.